# Possible to have a password-protected/weak-encrypted ZIP file with a data descriptor?

Tags: python, zip, compression, zlib, deflate

Is it possible to have ZIP file that has a data descriptor, and so the compressed size of each file is *after* its data, and have it password-protected via ZIP's "weak" encryption mechanism?

Context: am working on a streaming unZIP function for Python, specifically adding decryption support. Not being able to depend on the compressed size known before the data makes it... awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
UEsDBC0ACQAIAPBaJFMAAPBa//////////8BABQALQEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiTFa
LaeEC1Hn3rkwrUpSKqBmSpAtoQ1LulBLBwidP2y1GQAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAFBLAQIeAy0A
CQAIAPBaJFOdP2y1GQAAAA4AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwEQAAAAAtUEsFBgAAAAABAAEALwAA
AGQAAAAAAA==
```

Made with [Info-ZIP's zip](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html) thusly:

```
echo -n 'hello, hello!\0' | zip -e | cat > foo.zip
```

(password: foo)

Comment: Ah thanks... I see it has a data descriptor. But I realise I was a bit confused about the implications of that. For some reason I thought it means the compressed size of the data is _only_ available in the data descriptor after the data. However, in this case, I see its available before the data (in the "extra" data area)

Comment: Doesn't have to. I have updated the answer with a zip file without that.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask, how you made this file?

Comment: Thanks! (Also, I might be mis-parsing the file, but so far it looks like it _doesn't_ have the optional signature at the beginning of the data descriptor, which I don't think I've seen before)

Comment: (A good chance I am mis-parsing the file... accidentally "decrypting" the non-encrypted data descriptor)

Comment: It does, in fact, have the data descriptor signature.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies